# .NET array - difference between "Length", "Count()" and "Rank"

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

What's the difference between "Length", "Count()" and "Rank" for a .NET array?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`Length` is the property of an array object and using it is the most effective way to determine the count of elements in the array ([Array.Length in MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx)).

`Count()` is a [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) extension method that does effectively the same. It applies to arrays because arrays are enumerable objects. It's preferred to use `Length`, because `Count()` is likely to be more expensive (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/981254/501518) for further discussion and [MSDN documentation on Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count.aspx) for reference).

`Rank` is the property that returns the number of dimensions (a different thing entirely). When you declare an array `int[,] myArray = new int[5,10];`, the `Rank` of it will be 2, but it will hold a total of 50 elements ([MSDN on Rank property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.rank.aspx)).

Comment: Is there any difference between "Length" and "Count()" instead of "Count()" is a LINQ extension method?

Comment: @Alex Maslakov: array type doesn't have a `Count()` method itself afaik

Comment: @Alex, Length belongs to the Array class, and Count is an extension method for all Enumerable types. I guess the Array.Length is faster than Count(). However, with Count() you can use a predicate to count the number of items that satisfy a condition.

Comment: There is the extra level of indirection, but for arrays, Count() won't enumerate the array: arrays implement ICollection so the Count property is what is going to be called ultimately by the count extension method, and that is the same as Length.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy: that is correct, however, in common case the `Count()` call is likely to be more expensive (even if in some cases it is equally inexpensive), which is exactly what I wrote, or am I missing something?

Comment: I was merely adding some information, not attacking your answer.

Comment: @Dyppl: your answer is leaving out the fact that you can also call the ICollection Count property directly, via `var count = ((ICollection)myArray).Count;`  And of course if the array is passed as a collection in the first place, then it just uses it directly,as `var count = col.Count;`.

Answer (score 24):

- `Length`: **Total number of elements** in an *array*
- `LongLength`: Same as `Length`, but returned as `long` (in case it's >= 2<sup>31</sup>)
- `Count()`: LINQ *extension method* that works with other collection types as well
- `Rank`: Number of **dimensions** in array (always `1` for vectors). Only in .NET 3.5+.
- `GetLength()`, `GetLongLength()`: **Length** of a *certain dimension* of an array
- `GetLowerBound()`: Starting index of a certain dimension of an array; always `0` for vectors
- `GetUpperBound()`: Ending index of a certain dimension of an array; always `Length - 1` for vectors

Interestingly, there's no `GetLongUpperBound()` or `GetLongLowerBound()`...

---

Now that we're on the topic, what is the difference between an *array* and a *vector* in .NET?

### Arrays versus Vectors

Vectors are what you normally call "1D" arrays in C#. However, 1-dimensional arrays are actually not of a type like `int[]`, but they're of the type `int[*]`. C# doesn't directly support them; however, they can be created with `Array.CreateInstance`, and can have non-zero lower bounds. They are, however, slightly slower than vectors, because vectors are directly supported in the CLR. Because 1-dimensional arrays are actually rarely used, C# has decided not to support them (although it *can* use them through the use of the `var` keyword, from another module which declares them!).

Answer (score 2):

- `Length` is a property returning the number of elements in an `Array`.
- `Count()` is a LINQ extension that does the same on an `IEnumerable`. Optionally, it can take a predicate as parameter, and will return the number of elements that satisfy it.
- `Rank` is a property returning the number of dimensions in an `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

*Length* is the size of the array. 
*Count()* is the amount of items in the array (from *system.linq*) 
Rank returns the number of dimensions (a[][] = 2, a[] = 1).

Comment: Actually, the rank of an array of type `T[][]` is 1.  It is a one-dimensional array whose elements are one-dimensional arrays.  The type whose rank is 2 is `T[,]`.

Answer (score 0):

Well `.Count()` is for `IEnumerable`, `List` or `ArrayList` types. While `Length` is for `Array`.

`Rank` is to denote the **number of dimensions** of an array.

Comment: And for Dictionary? (*Count*)

Answer (score 0):

`Length` is a property of `Array` since C# 1.x

`Count()`is an extension method of `IEnumerable<T>`, because now every `T[]` implements `IEnumerable<T>` implicitly.

**Note that for an array, `Count()` is usually much slower than `Length`,** because accessing `Length` property is O(1), while `Count` is for `IEnumerable<T>`, so the program needs to go through the collection and get its count, that is O(n).

`Rank` gives the demensions of the array.

Comment: Not `much slower` because implementation of `Count()` method has some built-in optimizations just for that case. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981254/is-the-linq-count-faster-or-slower-than-list-count-or-array-length

Comment: @Dyppl: Well, `much slower` doesn't base on a precise standard. It costs 10x time, so I say "much slower". But the fact is, the 10x time is less than 0.1 second.

Comment: but I don't know about the "10x" in this case. It probably takes one more cast operation, that's basically nothing compared to **really slow** implementation involving iteration over all N elements.

Comment: @Dyppl: I tested with `Stopwatch`. `Count()` costs 10x time for an array with 10000 items.

Comment: well, okay, but the point is that it's not more complex assymptotically

Comment: This answer should be updated: it is not true that Count() will enumerate the array: there is an optimisation in there for anything that implements ICollection.

Comment: Can you add your benchmark results to the answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.).