# Better way to update values in string[]

Tags: c#

I am looking for a better way to update values in my List/Array:

My code is like -

```
String[] values = baseValue.Split(new []{'+'});
```

Because the 'values' can have decimal/string values -  I want to update items in this list to remove any value after decimal -

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.Count(); i++)
{
    decimal newvalue;
    if (Decimal.TryParse(values[i], out newvalue))
    {
        values[i] = Decimal.ToInt32(newvalue).ToString();
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve above using Linq/without Linq ?

Comment: Better? Better for what? Readability? Maintainability? Performance? Cleverness? LOC count? Something else?

Comment: performance-wise this is quicker than any LINQ expression

Comment: Well. LINQ works with sequences in a functional way: it doesn't modify the original sequence, it just transforms the original one into something different. Your task is however just adjusting the existing sequences. I would say that implementing this task in LINQ (although possible) is quite unnatural, and therefore should be avoided.

Comment: By the way, your title is wrong: `IEnumerable<...>` is read-only, so you cannot update it (only calculate a new one).

Comment: Please do not put c# in the title, that is what tags are for

Comment: Just a improvement: use value.Length instead of Count()

Comment: Quite unclear what the goal is.  Random guess: consider linquifying it by also using deferred execution.  Write an iterator.

Comment: @ivowiblo  Out of curiosity, why would `Length` be better than `Count()` in this situation?

Comment: `.Count()` is a LINQ extension function, whereas `Length` is a property of the array itself. I would guess that `Length` would run faster. `Count` probably ends up calling `Length`, though I haven't opened Reflector to find out for sure.

Comment: @BrianSnow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646449/net-array-difference-between-length-count-and-rank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use string operations, instead of converting to `decimal` then to `int` and finally back to `string`.

```
string[] values = baseValue.Split('+');
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    int pos = values[i].IndexOf('.');
    if (pos >= 0) {
        values[i] = values[i].Substring(0, pos);
    }
}
```

Of cause no rounding occurs here.

---

`String.Split` has an overload with one argument `params char[] separator`. Because of the `params` keyword, you can specify as many characters as you want, without having to create an array explicitly.

```
string[] result = s.Split('x', 'y', 'z');
```

---

Use `values.Length` which is a property built into array types. `values.Count()` is a LINQ extension method, which enumerates all the array items and is therefore not efficient.

Comment: -1: This has quite a few drawbacks: (1) It is not culture-dependent as the original code. (2) It doesn't work for whole numbers like 1, 2, etc. (3) It recognizes everything with a dot in it as a number like `How.Are.You`.

Comment: +1 although in the general case you should probably use [the current locale's decimal separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) rather than just hard-coding "."

Comment: Since you are dealing with an array, `.Length` might be better than `.Count()` here.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: If the lines are read from a file, they might have another culture than the current culture. I cannot provide a solution for the culture problem here, since I do not know the actual situation. However, you are right to point out this problem. It does work for whole numbers, beacause then `values[i]` already contains the desired result, namely a number without decimal part!

Comment: The OP is not very clear on what the values can be exactly. Does `decimal/string` mean that values can be something different than numbers and could contain a point ('.') even when not a number, or does it mean that they contain decimal numbers as string? Also he says "remove any value after decimal". I assume that he means "remove any value after the decimal point".

Comment: @mdm: You are right of cause. I just copied the OP's code and corrected it later.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an extension method:

```
 public static void ConvertDecimalToInts(this string[] values)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count(); i++)
        {
            decimal newvalue;
            if (Decimal.TryParse(values[i], out newvalue))
            {
                values[i] = Decimal.ToInt32(newvalue).ToString();
            }
        }    
    }
```

And use it as so:

```
        String[] values = baseValue.Split(new[] { '+' });
        values.ConvertDecimalToInts();
```

Answer (score 0):

Olivier's answer is probably better in that it doesn't require three conversions, but you can do this with Linq if you wish:

```
values = baseValue.Split('+')
                  .Select(v => Decimal.ToInt32(Decimal.Parse(v)).ToString());
```

Comment: This would throw an exception if not every string in the source collection is a valid representation of a number.