# Dictionary.Count performance

Tags: c#, dictionary

**This question seems to be nonsense. The behaviour cannot be reproduced reliably.**

Comparing the following test programs, I observed a *huge* performance difference between the first and the second of the following examples (the first example is by factor ten slower than the second):

First example (slow):

```
interface IWrappedDict {
    int Number { get; }
    void AddSomething (string k, string v);
}

class WrappedDict : IWrappedDict {
    private Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string> ();


    public void AddSomething (string k, string v) {
        dict.Add (k, v);
    }

    public int Number { get { return dict.Count; } }
}

class TestClass {
    private IWrappedDict wrappedDict;

    public TestClass (IWrappedDict theWrappedDict) {
        wrappedDict = theWrappedDict;
    }

    public void DoSomething () {
        // this function does the performance test
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
            var c = wrappedDict.Number; wrappedDict.AddSomething (...);
        }
    }
}
```

Second example (fast):

```
// IWrappedDict as above
class WrappedDict : IWrappedDict {
    private Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string> ();
    private int c = 0;

    public void AddSomething (string k, string v) {
        dict.Add (k, v); ++ c;
    }

    public int Number { get { return c; } }
}
// rest as above
```

Funnily, the difference vanishes (the first example gets fast as well) if I change the type of the member variable `TestClass.wrappedDict` from `IWrappedDict` to `WrappedDict`. My interpretation of this is that `Dictionary.Count` re-counts the elements every time it is accessed and that potential caching of the number of elements is done by compiler optimization only.

Can anybody confirm this? Is there any way to get the number of elements in a `Dictionary` in a performant way?

Comment: It is surprising considering `Getting the value of this(count) property is an O(1) operation` [Dictionary.Count - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhcy256f.aspx)

Comment: I've put together a test from your code, and for me the slow code takes only ~30% longer than the fast code.

Comment: Re "What should I do?" (mod-flag): post the code that you have that **shows what you are seeing**, including your timing mechanism. Make it runnable, so we can see what is up.

Comment: Yes, I would, if I could narrow down the problem. But I can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sound like your timing is off; I get:

```
#1: 330ms
#2: 335ms
```

when running the following *in release mode, outside of the IDE*:

```
public void DoSomething(int count) {
    // this function does the performance test
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        var c = wrappedDict.Number; wrappedDict.AddSomething(i.ToString(), "a");
    }
}
static void Execute(int count, bool show)
{
    var obj1 = new TestClass(new WrappedDict1());
    var obj2 = new TestClass(new WrappedDict2());

    GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    obj1.DoSomething(count);
    watch.Stop();
    if(show) Console.WriteLine("#1: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    obj2.DoSomething(count);
    watch.Stop();
    if(show) Console.WriteLine("#2: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
static void Main()
{
    Execute(1, false); // for JIT
    Execute(1000000, true); // for measuring
}
```

Basically: "cannot reproduce". Also: for completeness, no: `.Count` does not count all the items (it already knows the count), nor does the compiler add any magic automatic caching code (note: there are a few limited examples of things like that; for example, the JIT can remove bounds-checking on a `for` loop over a *vector*).

Comment: I have to admit that most probably you are right. Today it's impossible for me to reproduce the effect I got yesterday. Maybe it has to do with profiling in debug mode? I am completely confused. Yesterday runtime of my program dropped from 60 seconds to 18 seconds by caching the result of `.Count`, and now I get 18 seconds even with calling `.Count` every time. It's strange.

Comment: @JohnB possibly; if you profile in debug mode, all bets are off

Answer (score 5):

No, `Dictionary.Count` does *not* recount the elements every time it's used. The dictionary maintains a count, and should be as fast as your second version.

I suspect that in your test of the second example, you already had `WrappedDict` instead of `IWrappedDict`, and this is actually about interface member access (which is always virtual) and the JIT compiling inlining calls to the property when it knows the concrete type.

If you still believe `Count` is the problem, you should be able to edit your question to show a short but complete program which demonstrates both the fast and slow versions, including how you're timing it all.

Comment: That cannot be an explanation, since then my "Second example" would have to be slow as well.

Comment: @JohnB: As I say, I *suspect* that when you were testing your second example, you were using `WrappedDict` directly... in other words, I suspecty your diagnostics are incorrect. If you disagree, the best way to prove otherwise is to edit your question to show a short but complete program demonstrating the difference.

Comment: But [an array does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646449/net-array-difference-between-length-count-and-rank/6646527#6646527)(?).

Comment: @PeterMortensen: As noted in the comments on that answer, it's incorrect. (And note that that's about the `Count()` method, not the `Count` property discussed here.)

Answer (score 3):

No, a dictionary or hashtable never iterates the entries to determine the length.

It will (or should) always keep track of the number of entries.

Thus, the time complexity is `O(1)`.

Comment: But [an array does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646449/net-array-difference-between-length-count-and-rank/6646527#6646527)(?).