# Efficient way to determine collection has at least 2 items

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2015

I am aware that Linq provides capability to determine if a collection has any items. Such as

```
var anyCategories= categories.Any();
```

This is very efficient because if it finds at least one item then the iteration stops. Now what if I want to know if a collection has at least 2 items. Here is the code i have currently:

```
var atLeastTwoCategories= categories.Count() > 1;
```

This one will go through the whole collection then if the count is bigger than one. I think this is very inefficient. Does Linq or .NET provide a better way to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simplest approach is:

```
var atLeastTwoCategories= categories.Skip(1).Any();
```

And I'm assuming that by 'collection' you actually mean any `IEnumerable` supported by LINQ including, say, a SQL data source. For `List` and `Array` .NET may optimize Count down to an O(1) operation anyway so it makes no difference there. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/981283/224370 but for 'collections' coming from a database or where it's costly to iterate over the elements, this approach is faster.

Answer (score 7):

To implement an `AtLeast(n)` operation that returns true if the collection contains `n` or more items you need to iterate through the collection `n - 1` times then check to see if there are any more items remaining.  Or to put it in code:

```
public static bool AtLeast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int n)
{
    if (n < 1)
        return true; // or exception, you choose
    if (n == 1)
        return collection.Any();
    return collection.Skip(n - 1).Any();
}
```

This will not require a full iteration of the collection so should be reasonably efficient.

You can try to improve on the efficiency by adding specific versions for `Array<T>`, `List<T>` and any other types that you can think of a better way.  For instance:

```
public static bool AtLeast<T>(this Array<T> array, int n)
{
    return array.Length >= n;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the method Count(), use the property Count! (remove the brackets)

This should just return the length of the array without attempting any filtering logic.

Comment: Are you aware of the optimizations on Count in LINQ? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/981283/224370

Comment: He could be using an IEnumerable...and in that case there is no .Count property.

Comment: "But you still pay the minor overhead of the cast and interface call." Linq behind the scenes tries to cast to ICollection for Count() and if the cast succeeds just calls ICollection.Count. Question for op is, what is the actual incoming collection type? Many already have 0(1) implementations such as arrays, List, HashSet<>, Dictionary<>, etc.