# Improving efficiency of multiple Counts

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My question is about "Best Practice" and/or "Improving Efficiency" for queries and count in MVC. Let me start by giving the scenario.
In my database I have a table of objects that have Type A, B, or C and Status 1, 2, 3 or 4. On the front page of my application I am displaying the number of the different objects with the different statuses (object A status 1: 22, object A status 2: 35, ... etc)

At the moment what I am doing is making a query to first find all objects with type A and set that to a variable. I then do something like this: `variable.Where(x => x.status = 1).Count()` for each status. This does gives me what I want and need, but as you can imagine it is not the most efficient way to do and with a large amount of records this will take quite a lot of time.

My question now is: how do I improve my code so that I get the counts of the different statuses in the least amount of time?

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: If they don't change often, cache the values

Comment: If have materialized your query to `List<T>` then its so fast that you could not measure it. Refer [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981254/is-the-linq-count-faster-or-slower-than-list-count-or-array-length) and in particular that by Sam Saffron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least you should use `Count` with predicate `Count(x => x.status == 1)`. This overloading function does not load entities from DB but just counts them on DB side with efficient SQL query.

Comment: That should be `==`, not `=`