# Iterating through a list, but can't access distinct item values

Tags: c#, list, foreach, ienumerable, pdfsharp

I am building invoices with [PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/).

This is my SQL table (`tblTripsPerMonth`):

[image]

I've bound it to an `ObservableCollection` (`PaidTrips`).

The goal is to create one (1) PDF for each distinct "CompanyName" in the `LicenseHolderID` column.
To achieve this, I convert to a `List`, and group by `LicenseHolderID`.

```
var paidTrips = PaidTrips
    .GroupBy(p => new {
        p.LicenseHolderID
})
.ToList();
```

After that, I iterate over the list with a `foreach`-loop:

```
foreach (var trip in paidTrips) {
    
    // I grab the distinct name
    string licenseholder = trip.Key.LicenseHolderID.ToString();
    
    // I summarize many of the columns
    decimal totalPayment = trip.Sum(x => x.Payment);
    decimal totalPaymentNet = trip.Sum(x => x.Payment);
    decimal totalOrderFee = trip.Sum(x => x.Payment);
    decimal totalPaymentFee = trip.Sum(x => x.Payment);
    
    // I grab the first value of some other columns, which won't change
    string licenseholderInvoiceID = trip.Select(x => x.LicenseHolderInvoiceID).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
    string ridelRegionInvoiceID = trip.Select(x => x.RidelRegionInvoiceID ).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

// Creating PDF document using PDFsharp:
// PDFsharp code
// PDFsharp code
// PDFsharp code
}
```

I am able to create a PDF-document, one for each distinct `LicenseHolderID`, by adding the `licenseHolderID`-string to the file-path of PDFsharps `document.Save()`.

But I am not able to fill the PDF-document with all the information I need.
I have the summarized amounts - *good*, because I absolutely need to display the full invoice amount.
But -- I also need to go into detail. I do **not** have amounts per `VehicleID`.

For "CompanyName1", that'd be AG4203000002 and AG4203000003, with their corresponding row data.

I did do this...

```
IEnumerable<string> vehicleIds = trip
    .Select(x => x.VehicleID)
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray();
string vehicle = string.Join(", ", vehicleIds);
```

...in order to separate the `VehicleID` distinct values from eachother.
I then put the `string vehicle` into PDFsharps way of drawing text onto the PDF (`DrawString`):

```
gfx.DrawString(vehicle, /* font and color customization */);
```

Which gives me the correct amount of `VehicleID` for each `LicenseHolderID`, but in one, long string... Not optimal.

**Which brings me to my question:** **A)**: I need to bring along the row data of the other columns pertaining to the distinct vehicles in `VehicleID`, so that I can fill in details in my PDFs, and not just the summarized values, and **B)**: if the solution to **A)** involves getting rid of the long, hacky string (`vehicle`), that'd be optimal, if not - that's okay too.

**UPDATE (adding code from @Dai's answer):**

```
// PaidTrip = My holder class, which I've bound to a ObservableCollection (PaidTrips)
var paidTrips = PaidTrips.ToList(); // I was unsure about this one
IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, PaidTrip>> tripsGroupedByCompany = paidTrips.GroupBy(pt => pt.LicenseHolderID);

foreach (IGrouping<String, PaidTrip>> companyGroup in tripsGroupedByCompany) {
    
    string licenseHolderId = companyGroup.Key;
    gfx.DrawString(/* code goes foo */);

    // I tried adding Key here, but that gave me a squiggly under "t.VehicleID"
    var groupedByVehicle = companyGroup.GroupBy(t => t.VehicleID);
    
    foreach (IGrouping<String, PaidTrip> vehicleGroup in groupedByVehicle) {

        // This is where I get a red squiggly; under Key
        String vehicleId = groupedByVehicle.Key;

        gfx.DrawString(/* code goes foo */);
        
        foreach (PaidTrip trip in vehicleGroup) {
      
            gfx.DrawString(/* code goes foo */);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error:

> CS1061: IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, PaidTrip>> does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no accessible extension method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, PaidTrip>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is this in an **interactive** desktop application using WPF, or is this a "headless" background service or web-application? Because if it's the latter, there is zero reason to use `ObservableCollection`. Also, why does your table have a `tbl` pefix? (You should always avoid using Systems Hungarian Notation prefixes for database objects, otherwise your system ends-up looking silly when you change a `TABLE` to a `VIEW` or vice-versa, and more besides).

Comment: Tip: Change `.GroupBy(p => new {p.LicenseHolderID } )` to just `GroupBy( p => p.LicenseHolderID )`. You don't need a single-member anonymous-class, and (imo) anonymous-classes should not be used anymore because they are (generally, in most cases) inferior to ValueTuples.

Comment: Do you have a correctly-configured `DbContext` you can use to directly query the `Vehicles` table and other trip information? Your `tblTripsPerMonth` table seems to be denormalized (i.e. designed incorrectly) so you should fix that...

Comment: Another tip: generally speaking you never need to use `ToArray`, instead use `ToList` (as it's faster in all cases), and if you are going to use either `ToArray` or `ToList` then store the result into a `T[]` or `List<T>` respectively, not `IEnumerable<T>` because when you use `IEnumerable<T>` then the CLR can't make fast non-virtual calls to `List<T>` and `Array`'s members (e.g. Linq's `.Count()` extension always slower than `List<T>.Count` and sometimes even takes `O(n)` to run, eww).

Comment: @Dai Note that many of the Linq extension methods on `IEnumerable` (like `Count`) actually _do_ use the native properties (like `Length` or `Count`) of both arrays and lists. So it's not true that `IEnumerable.Count()` is always slower than `List.Count`.

Comment: @DStanley It **is** slower: Before .NET 6 (or maybe .NET 7 if it gets punted again) the Linq `.Count()` extension both is not inlined and it only checks for `IList<T>.Count` and `ICollection<T>.Count` but not `IReadOnlyCollection<T>.Count` (nor `IReadOnlyList<T>.Count`), otherwise it will iterate over the entire collection to get the count - this is because checking for `IReadOnlyCollection` in Linq is also _relatively_ expensive (see this thread: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42254 ) Also see this article: https://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-12/linq-count-considered-occasionally-harmful

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the information and tips. I greatly appreciate that. I have implemented them all, and will now take a look at the answer you posted. I do not even know what `DbContext` is, so I will have to look into that. I have a `ID int identity(1,1) primary key` column in my table as well, but that might not be what you mean. I will, when time permits, look into how I've structured my table and database, and have your comment in mind.

Comment: And yes, this is in fact a WPF-application. :-)

Comment: @Dai both `List<T>` and arrays implement `ICollection<T>` so they will use the shortcut. And the shortcut has been in Linq since day 1 (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981254) from 2009). There's no need to avoid `ToList` _just_ because you think `Count` is slow. There are _other_ reasons you may want to avoid `ToList` but `Count` being slow is not one of them. Finally, casting the result to `IEnumerable<T>` will have no effect on `Count` performance. Linq will still check if the actual _object_ implements `ICollection<T>` and shortcut the `Count` call.

Comment: @Dai I think (based on the second article you linked) you're confusing the omissions of `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` from the chortcut with lists and arrays in general.

Comment: @DStanley _it's complicated_ - for a very similar question on SO in the past couple of years I wrote a benchmark for various Linq operations on different collection interfaces and that was my conclusion. Please note that I do largely agree with you, and that 90% of the time the difference is splitting-hairs and this conversation is entirely academic, but I distinctly remember that Linq has a lot of `callvirt` instructions in it which can be optimized away _only_ by making non-virtual calls directly to non-interface collection type members. Also I've been awake for 36 hours so I'm rambling now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to bring along the row data of the other columns pertaining to the distinct vehicles in `VehicleId`, so that I can fill in details in my PDFs, and not just the summarized values.

If I understand you correctly, for each company (`LicenseHolderId`) you want their relevant `Trip` objects, but grouped by `VehicleId` - that's straightforward, just add another `GroupBy` - and you can iterate over them in an inner `foreach`:

```
List<Trip> paidTrips = ...

IEnumerable< IGrouping<String,Trip> > tripsGroupedByCompany = paidTrips.GroupBy( pt => pt.LicenseHolderId );

foreach( IGrouping<String,Trip> companyGroup in tripsGroupedByCompany )
{
    String licenseHolderId = companyGroup.Key;

    gfx.DrawString( "Company: " + licenseHolderId + "\r\n" );

    var groupedByVehicle = companyGroup.GroupBy( t => t.VehicleId );
    foreach( IGrouping<String,Trip> vehicleGroup in groupedByVehicle )
    {
        String vehicleId = vehicleGroup.Key;
        
        gfx.DrawString( "\tVehicle: " + vehicleId + "\r\n" );

        foreach( Trip trip in vehicleGroup )
        {
            gfx.DrawString( $"\t\tTrip: {trip.Year}-{trip.Month:00}. {trip.PaymentNet,11:C2}\r\n" );
        }
    }
}
```

- I added some formatting instructions and characters which only really apply to text-mode (console applications), not PDF rendering, but if you're curious:

  - I used tab characters (`\t`) to indicate indent so related data is visually grouped.
  - I used formatting specifier `:00` to ensure the `Month` value is displayed as a 2-digit value with a leading zero.
  - I used formatting specifier `,11:C2` to ensure the `PaymentNet` value is formatted as a Currency value with 2 decimal places, and is always left-padded to at-least 11 characters width.
- This will give you output like this (below).
- Note that while in your source-data each `VehicleId` has only a single trip associated with it, my code above *allows* a single `VehicleId` to have multiple trips with both the same, and different, `LicenseHolderId` values, though the sample print-out below only shows 1 trip per Vehicle.

```
Company: CompanyName1
    Vehicle: AG4203000002
        Trip: 2021-07. $107,088.68

    Vehicle: AG4203000003
        Trip: 2021-07. $138,761.32

Company: CompanyName2:
    Vehicle: AG4203000004
        Trip: 2021-07. $129,264.15

    Vehicle: AG4203000005
        Trip: 2021-07.  $87,273.58
```

---

But note that this code above is bad because it *crosses concerns* (it does 2 separate things: it traverses a non-trivial object-graph, and it renders data to your PDF library).

A better design would *separate out* the graph-traversal (perhaps to a single extension method) thus making the PDF rendering code much simpler, however I cannot give you any code examples of this without knowing more about your database design and if/how you're using EF.

Comment: what an amazing answer - thank you so much for taking the time to write out such a thought-out response. One hick-up! I get a red squiggly under `Key` in `String vehicleId = groupedByVehicle.Key;` -- I played around with it, but couldn't figure out a work-around. I've added my new code to my original question, would you take a look? Also, out of curiosity, why do you use `String` instead of `string`?

Comment: @OleM My mistake. Change `groupedByVehicle.Key` to `vehicleGroup .Key`

Comment: Superb, thank you again. Accepting your answer. One more thing before I scurry off; as is, with - for example - `gfx.DrawString(vehicleId /* more code */)` it adds all the `vehicleId`s ON TOP of eachother. Any idea how I could space them out or otherwise organize them?

Comment: @OleM I'm not familiar with PDFSharp so I can't say - but I do find it odd that you're generating a PDF by-hand - most of the time people just use Blink/Chromium+Puppeteer to convert HTML+CSS to PDF (not that I'd ever advocate using such a round-about (and memory-hogging) way, but the developer-productivity gains are _massive_ because you can crank-out a HTML+CSS template in under a few hours, compared to the _days to weeks_ it takes to hand-write PDF rendering code.

Comment: It's to do with the position (X,Y) of the `DrawString`, it seems. 
I am slowly starting to realize this is not the #1 way of doing things.. But I'm in too deep lol. Next time, I'll investigate something along those lines for sure.

Comment: Probably no point to add this here, but I solved it by defining `int y` outside of the `foreach`, replacing the int value with `y` in the `DrawString`, and adding `int += 50` inside the loop